# VS2013 Virtual Database how to use

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013

Im wondering for what the SQL database project template exists. I have created one and inserted a table with some col. Now i saved that, so i want to write Into that mdf-file Form a Windows forms project. I dont know how to acces that or even if this SQL project template is ment for that sort of usage. Is this a good solution for a local database?

Sry for that kind or basic question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database project exists so that you can store the database structure in source control, generate and deploy the database (or upgrade scripts).